# Choose which view to use through Typoscript

Tags: view, typo3, typoscript, extbase

If I have the following Typoscript to let a page render an action from a controller, could I also use it to set another view than the default?

```
  151 = USER_INT
  151 {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    pluginName = Pi1
    extensionName = WdProducts
    controller = Products
    vendorName = Bitmotion
    action = showFromTyposcriptAction

    switchableControllerActions {
      Products {
        1 = showFromTyposcript
      }
    }

    settings =< plugin.tx_wdproducts.settings
    persistence =< plugin.tx_wdproducts.persistence
    view =< plugin.tx_wdproducts.view
    update =< plugin.tx_wdproducts.update
  }
```

The view rendered is `ShowFromTyposcript.html`, but I want view `Show.html`. Or could I set another view from the controller, with `setTemplatePathAndFilename` (have tried but didn't get it to work)?

I use TYPO3 6.2.

Answer (score 1):

Create two plugins i.e.: `ShowFromTyposcript` and `Show` for each use required action as a first in `ext_localconf.php`, so you can just:

```
10 = USER
10 {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  extensionName = WdProducts
  pluginName = ShowFromTyposcript
  vendorName = Bitmotion
}

20 = USER
20 {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  extensionName = WdProducts
  pluginName = Show
  vendorName = Bitmotion
}
```

Other approach is using ONE common action for `forwarding` to other action(s) depending on conditions:

```
public function showFromTyposcriptAction(){
    if (intval(GeneralUtility::_GET('product'))>0){
        $this->forward('show');
    }
    ....
}


public function showAction(){
    $productUid = intval(GeneralUtility::_GET('product'));
    $product = $this->productRepository->finByUid($prodcutUid);
    ....
}
```

Comment: For the first approach, could I use same view for different action like this? The second approach I understand, thanks.

Comment: In Extbase the action name = view name.: i.e.: 'showAction' of `Product` controller is placed in `.../Product/Show.html` file, if you want to break that rule you need to use `StandaloneView` class: https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_fluid_1_1_view_1_1_standalone_view.html